# Mini-UPS schematic - load-sharing of battery pack and power source

Tags: power-supply, batteries, schematics, ups

I am a beginner working on a mini-UPS project for a low-power server (computer).

I've made the following schematic where I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Charge 3S 18650 battery pack BMS with 12.6V @1A
- Load-share between battery power and DC in @12V
- Pull maximum 2.5A from the DC in (I would like the computer to be able to pull more from the battery pack if there is a momentary peak)

I've watched a ton of videos and read about load sharing, how to connect multiple power supplies, etc. but I really would love to benefit from someone's experience to see if I am headed in the right direction. I added 2 Schottky diodes on the positive of the VOut on the two power sources so they wouldn't leach power from each other, as well as a capacitor to smooth interruptions. To simplify this, I didn't draw out the circuit of the BMS board connections to the batteries.

I am looking to answer the following questions:

1. Would this schematic work?
2. Regarding the load sharing - how does the "failover" between the DC in and the battery power work? Does it just happen when there is a drop in voltage, it will just start pulling current from the higher voltage source?
3. Do I need some kind of MCU and MOSFET setup to intelligently switch power? I thought I did, but have seen other setups like the one I've got here referenced in DIY videos - what are the disadvantages of the "dumb" approach?

Here is the schematic:

[image: mini-ups schematic]

Here are the parts referenced:

- [CC buck convertor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V7F5K8T)
- [Boost convertor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L64GJ42)
- [BMS board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JMY631D)

Comment: Try D201 (?) dual FETs for low drop instead of diodes. Start with specs for V tolerance, eff. And Ah

Comment: Hey. Could you be a little more specific about that? What are dual FETs (I searched D201 FET on Google and didn't find anything that seemed relevant)? What do you mean "low drop"?

Comment: 10mV vs 700mV. Try DW01-P